# Error Messages partial not showing

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model called Video, which takes in user_id, question, and video_cid.

The validates seem to have been set, as the form does not save if it doesn't meet requirements. However, the error messages partial shows no error messages :(.

Here's how the model looks like ->

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: videos
#
#  id         :integer          not null, primary key
#  user_id    :integer
#  video_cid  :string(255)
#  question   :string(255)
#  created_at :datetime
#  updated_at :datetime
#

class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user

 validates  :user_id, presence: true
 validates  :question, presence: true
 validates  :video_cid, presence: true

end
```

Here's how the videos/new view looks like ->

```
<% provide(:title, "Final step, Record a video of yourself") %>

<%= form_for @video do |f| %>
 <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
 <%= f.label :question %>
 <%= select(:video, :question, 
                [
                    ['Why would you be effective in a sales/business development role in China?', 
                        'Why would you be a valuable addition to an international team in China? '], 
                    ['What is your most significant accomplishment or the best example of your leadership skills in China?', 
                        'What is your most significant accomplishment or the best example of your leadership skills in China?'],
                     ['How would you help solve the biggest challenges Chinese companies and investors face when doing business abroad?',
                        'How would you help solve the biggest challenges Chinese companies and investors face when doing business abroad? ']
                ]) %>

 <%= render 'nimbb' %>
 <%= f.hidden_field :video_cid, value: "" %>
 <%= f.submit "Submit the Video", class: "button" %>
<% end %>
```

I use javascript to set the hidden value for :video_cid like so. The form should technically only pass if the user records a video of himself, and therefore updates the hidden value in the form ->

```
// Global variable to hold player's reference.
var _Nimbb;

// Global variable to hold the guid of the recorded video.

// Event: Nimbb Player has been initialized and is ready.
function Nimbb_initCompleted(idPlayer)
{
  // Get a reference to the player since it was successfully created.
  _Nimbb = document[idPlayer];
}

// Event: the video was saved.
function Nimbb_videoSaved(idPlayer)
{
  document.getElementById('video_video_cid').value = _Nimbb.getGuid();
}
```

This is how the controller looks like -->

```
class VideosController < ApplicationController
  before_action :signed_in_user

  def new
    if current_user.video.present?
      redirect_to current_user
    else
      @video = current_user.build_video
    end
  end

  def create 
    @video = current_user.build_video(video_params)
    if @video.save
        flash[:success] = "Video Created!"
        redirect_to root_url
    else
        redirect_to new_video_path
    end
  end


  private

    def video_params
      params.require(:video).permit(:video_cid,:question)
    end
end
```

this is how the error messages partial looks like:

```
<% if object.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
    <div class="alert alert-error">
      The form contains <%= pluralize(object.errors.count, "error") %>.
    </div>
    <ul>
    <% object.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
      <li>* <%= msg %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `create` method to:

```
def create 
  @video = current_user.build_video(video_params)
  if @video.save
    flash[:success] = "Video Created!"
    redirect_to root_url
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

The form now will be displayed directly after your application rejects form data, without redirection, so it has `Video` object instantiated in `create` action, with its errors. In your original form, you were redirecting user to new video path after video saving failure, so the `new` action was being fired again, with new "clean" `Video` instance.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
<%= form_for(@video, :validate => true) do |f| %>
```

instead of

```
<%= form_for @video do |f| %>
```

And in your video controller, your create method should be like this

```
def create 
  @video = current_user.build_video(video_params)
  respond_to do |format|
    if @video.save
      flash[:success] = "Video Created!"
      format.html {redirect_to( :controller => "controller_name", :action => "action_name" )}
    else
      format.html {render :action => "action_name"}
    end
  end
end
```